# Creating dynamic objects in a loop - array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Basically I have two exact same divs and I want to add to both of them Bootstrap 4 color palette. Hard coding it is easy but I would like to do it in a dynamic way so theoretically future divs can have color palettes without writing new code manually.

The divs are (only the id is different):

```
<div id="myContainer">
      <a class="color-picker">Pick color</a>
      <input class="box" type="text" value="Write about yourself here">
  </div>

<div id="myContainer2">
  <a class="color-picker">Pick color</a>
  <input class="box" type="text" value="Write about yourself here">
```

If I write this code, everything works fine:

```
var colorPickerArray = [];

$(function(){
    colorPickerArray[0] = $('#myContainer .color-picker');
    colorPickerArray[0].colorpicker();
    colorPickerArray[0].on('changeColor', function(e){
      $('#myContainer .color-picker').empty();
      $('#myContainer .color-picker').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
      if(e.color==null)
        $(this).val('transparent').css('background-color', '#fff');//tranparent
      else
        $('#myContainer .box').css('color', e.color.toHex())
    });
  });

$(function(){
    colorPickerArray[1] = $('#myContainer2 .color-picker');
    colorPickerArray[1].colorpicker();
    colorPickerArray[1].on('changeColor', function(e){
      $('#myContainer2 .color-picker').empty();
      $('#myContainer2 .color-picker').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
      if(e.color==null)
        $(this).val('transparent').css('background-color', '#fff');//tranparent
      else
        $('#myContainer2 .box').css('color', e.color.toHex())
    });
  });
```

It's just a duplication with different keys (0 and 1) and different divs ('#myContainer' and 'myContainer2'). But when I transform this code to a loop, it doesn't work:

```
var resizeArr = ['#myContainer', '#myContainer2'];

$(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < resizeArr.length; i++) {
        colorPickerArray[i] = $(resizeArr[i] + ' .color-picker');
        colorPickerArray[i].colorpicker();
        colorPickerArray[i].on('changeColor', function(e){
        $(resizeArr[i] + ' .color-picker').empty();
        $(resizeArr[i] + ' .color-picker').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        if(e.color==null)
            $(this).val('transparent').css('background-color', '#fff');//tranparent
        else

            $(resizeArr[i] + ' .box').css('color', e.color.toHex())
    });
    }
  });
```

The actual code is exactly the same, just duplicated by the loop this time. Is it because changing the value of i affects the event listeners? What should I do instead of using arrays here?

### Edit

I did come out with a solution to create those dynamic color palettes and I would like to share it for whom it may help. But please I would still love to know why the previous method doesn't work, just for deeper understanding of js.

Anyway, here is the solution:

```
$('body > div .color-picker').mousedown(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    for (var i = 0; i < resizeArr.length; i++) {
        if (target.is($(resizeArr[i] + ' .color-picker i'))) {
          var a = $(resizeArr[i] + ' .color-picker');
                a.colorpicker();
                a.on('changeColor', function(e){
                    var b = (a[0].parentElement);
                    b = '#' + b.id 
                $(b + ' .color-picker').empty();
                $(b + ' .color-picker').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
                if(e.color==null)
                    $(this).val('transparent').css('background-color', '#fff');//tranparent
                else
                    $(b + ' .color-picker').val(e.color).css('background-color', e.color);
                    $(b + ' .box').css('color', e.color.toHex())
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: why is the else block different when you use loop?

Comment: Thanks I edited it out to prevent confustion but it doen't solve the problem

Comment: one problem i see is you're using resizeArr[i] in event 'changeColor', i is resizeArr.length+1 when it executes due to scoping. try using let or an iife. I could be wrong since i didnt run your code, just a suggestion

Comment: Nice thanks Chir you were right that was the problem! I didn't understnad how to write it with 'let' though. I just targeted the e.target.parentElement.id inside the 'on' function. Could you please explain? Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know how to mark your comment as the right answer I'm sorry I'm a bit new here

Comment: let is just another way to declare variable, so instead of 'var i' you would use 'let i', its es6 syntax tho so it wont work on really old browsers. The difference is var is function scoped and let is block scoped, so all the i in the callback function for event changeColor is referring to the i you declared in the forloop, which is resizeArr.length after the loop finishes.

Comment: It looks like this question contains an answer. Self-answers are very welcome here - would you delete it from the question, and paste it into an answer box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one problem i see is you're using resizeArr[i] in event 'changeColor', i is resizeArr.length when it executes due to scoping.
you can read more about let here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow method, by create current name variable for each colorPickerArray[i]:

```
var colorPickerArray = [];
var resizeArr = ['#myContainer', '#myContainer2'];
$(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < resizeArr.length; i++) {
        colorPickerArray[i] = $(resizeArr[i] + ' .color-picker');
        colorPickerArray[i].colorpicker();
        colorPickerArray[i].on('changeColor', function(e){
            //console.log(resizeArr[i]); //undefined here!
            var current = $(this).parent(); 
            var name = "#" + current[0].id; //console.log(current[0].id);
            $(name + ' .color-picker').empty();
            $(name + ' .color-picker').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
            if(e.color==null)
                $(this).val('transparent').css('background-color', '#fff');//tranparent
            else
                $(name + ' .color-picker').val(e.color).css('background-color', e.color);
                $(name + ' .box').css('color', e.color.toHex())
        });
    }
});
```